# loop and combine every two items

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Ive been trying to combine two items together on each loop, in the result there is a null, how do i check the "items" so not to get null's?

```
var oTitle = [],
items = ['a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2', 'c1', 'c2'];

for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
 oTitle[i] = {
    one: '' + items[i], // items[i].value
    two: '' + items[++i]
 };
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(oTitle)); 

// [{"one":"a1","two":"a2"},null,{"one":"b1","two":"b2"},null,{"one":"c1","two":"c2"}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you change the `i` in the `for` loop's body. When you call `items[++i]`, it actually changes the `i`. And at the second iteration your `i` is not `1`, but it is `2`.

`oTitles` `0` index is ready, but at the second iteration `i` is `2`. So you have values at `0 2 4` and so on. And for the indexes of `1,3,5` and other it has no values, so why it prints you `null`.

Actually for those indexes your array will contain not `null`, but `undefined`. But because you have used `JSON.stringify`, it converts `undefined` to `null`.

To achieve the expected result, you need to keep another variable for the indexing of your array or use `push` method of the array for indexing itself.

**INDEX**

```js
var oTitle = [];
var index = 0;
items = ['a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2', 'c1', 'c2'];

for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
 oTitle[index] = {
    one: '' + items[i], // items[i].value
    two: '' + items[++i]
 };
 index++;
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(oTitle));
```

**PUSH**

```js
var oTitle = [];
items = ['a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2', 'c1', 'c2'];

for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
 oTitle.push({
    one: '' + items[i], // items[i].value
    two: '' + items[++i]
 });
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(oTitle));
```

Comment: first snippet's last `index++` is wrong, it will cause each loop skip a number which will generate: `0,1`, `3,4`, `6,7`.......

Answer (score 1):

Just use `push()` and let the indexing of new array take care of itself

```js
var oTitle = [],
  items = ['a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2', 'c1', 'c2'];

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  oTitle.push({
    one: '' + items[i], // items[i].value
    two: '' + items[++i]
  });
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(oTitle, null, ' '))
```